# how to get full hash using short hash like git rev-parse

Tags: libgit2sharp

I have the short hash like `3cdd5dabcd`. How do I use **libgit2sharp** to retrieve the full hash like:

```
git rev-parse 3cdd5dabcd
```

I am thinking using the process to call **git** directly if **libgit2sharp** does not support this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up the blob by the short ID.  The `Blob` object will have the full `Id` as a property:

```
repo.Lookup<Blob>("3cdd5dabcd").Id;
```